# Is Dolby advanced audio suported?

Tags: 11.10, sound, ubuntu-netbook

Is there a way to use the [Dolby advanced audio](http://www.dolby.com/us/en/consumer/technology/pc/dolby-advanced-audio-v2.html) (v1) (this link is for version 2, they have removed version 1 but it's pretty much the same thing) on my netbook running ubuntu 11.10?

The laptop (toshiba NB550D) apparently comes with the Dolby advanced audio hardware. Inside windows there is an option to enable this via a tickbox inside the volume control settings.

Upon ticking the box (and rebooting) the sound goes from tinny and quiet, to being loud and normal in comparison to my external speakers. This only works in windows at the moment and has no effect in Ubuntu.

Is there a way to turn this on in Ubuntu?
Is it even supported?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)